# Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NeT MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I create a new asp MVC project, I found my project classes and directories look like that and can't add new class or delete. What can I do?

[image: this image describes what i talk about]

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please provide all details *in* your question and add more information about what you tried and what happend. Maybe it is good idea to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in "Class View".  From the "View" menu, select "Solution Explorer" to get back to what you are expecting to see.